# Hide statusbar with UINavigationBar barPositionTopAttached

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7-statusbar

I have rootViewController - `UINavigationController`.
As you know `UINavigationController` has `UINavigationBar`.
In iOS 7 `UINavigationBar` could be with barPosition topAttached.
I want to hide ON/OFF statusBar by clicking on button. But I also want that `UINavigationBar` should be always barPositionTopAttached.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return __statusBarHidden;
}

- (IBAction)tapShowPhotosButton:(id)sender {
    __statusBarHidden = !__statusBarHidden;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

For now `UINavigationBar` changed `barPosition` from `topAttached` to top, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write to technical support and get next answer:

> As stated in the documentation for , -positionForBar is called when the bar needs to know its position in its *new window*.  It will not be called when the status bar hides or unhides. The navigation controller handles resizing the navigation bar in response to a status bar change.  Unfortunately, UINavigationController does not provide any API to customize the navigation bar resizing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)tapShowPhotosButton:(id)sender 
{
    __statusBarHidden = !__statusBarHidden;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:__statusBarHidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

The Navigation Bar should automatically move with the status bar